# Excel trying to"Recover your information" - WinForm in Excel Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, add-in

Can any one help me with this?
I created a simple Excel add-in (using VS2012, Excel 2013, C#)
the Add-in has only a simple ribbon with 1 button and 1 simple form.
when the user clicks the button, the form is shown.
The thing is that when the user closes Excel, the attached image is displayed.

I replicated this by creating a Blank form that does nothing, but still the "Recovering your work" still appears.

this is the button-click event

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.ShowDialog();
```

[image: http://picpaste.com/SO.png]

Comment: This normally happens when your add-in prevents Excel from shutting down normally.  You are doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.  If you use the Marshal class then you're definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you please explain what I'm doing wrong? I just created a very simple ribbon with only one button and one form. the form doesn't have any code, neither does the ribbon.. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

After looking for windows Event Viewer, it turned out that "TitleBarDLL.dll" is causing Excel to crash.
investigating this file, it turned out that the problem is caused by Samsung Dual Monitor application (which installs with the monitor driver). Exiting/disabling the application fixes the issue.